# install civi-buildkit to have a working CiviCRM

Tags: crm

I am a newbie to CiviCRM. Could anyone please tell me how to install civi-buildkit and use it to have a working CiviCRM?
I have browsed the site https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit but it only mentions about downloading the tools.
Since I am new to this please help me with detailed steps.

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted by someone else at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/635/how-do-i-set-up-dev-environment-with-buildkit . You should check out the answers there.